# How to remember the trusted machine in an application

Tags: web-application, javascript, cookies, client-side

We need to remember trusted devices in our application. I have done some R&D for this and found out that Facebook achieves this using cookies. But, if I see Google, they don't use cookies, I guess.

How can they identify whether a user logged in from a new device or an existing device? They use MAC address (I guess not) or something else?

Comment: They don't use cookies? How do you know?

Comment: I guess they dont but I am not sure. As per my knowledge cookies are browser based. If we logged in from one browser, then we need not to authenticate in other browsers on the same machine. Please let me know in case you know anything about it. It would be great....

Comment: @user3040851 Just an FYI, the best way to tell if Google uses cookies is to login, double check it remembers you after reopening the browser, then clear the cookies from that browser.  When you go back to google, it should have forgotten you, so you would have to input your email again (instead of just a password).  Edit: Also, this works for any site.  If you think it uses cookies to store certain information, you can find out by clearing cookies and checking if it still remembers that information.

Comment: @schroeder Yes you are right, you are talking about somethig like remember me functionality. But if you noted that when we login to gmail from different machine, you get a mail saying that logged in from Unrecognized device. Once you authenticate it or logged in it, you will never get that email from google , no matter you clear your cookies, trying in different browser or any other thing , I just want to know that how can Google identifies whether taht device is recognized...??

Comment: Do no allow google chrome to work in background(in chrome's settings). Disable google's toolbar/plugins in those other browsers. Stop scheduled tasks associated with google chrome and let see if those browser would be able automatically signed in. Besides of cookies there in HTML5 capable browsers is additional application storage (HTML5 Local Storage) such as Indexed DB and etc. where additional information can be kept.

Comment: Hey Alex. I have tried all these stuff, but google still identifies my device. Yes, I have to login again but google still identifies my device. I had not got any email regarding New-Sign-In that we generally get when we try to login from different device. So I am just wondering how google identifies that. Can you please help me to figure this out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that nobody will give exact answer because it's Google's secret. I can only guess on that. If device you are talking is Android or Apple or you have some software from Google on laptop then all of them would really like to talk to Google. Install on android device "NoRoot firewall"  and you would be surprised how much your device fall in love with Google.

Comment: When I  traveling across US my phone/laptop are rejected to login to gmail when I'm flying from state to state, so changing geo location  (IP region) is a red flag for Google and they sending "New device attempted to login"   even if it's the same device with the same credentials. They offer to login to webmail to confirm that me is me, after that all my devices connecting with no problem. Don't forget that Google's business is data mining, so every device should have association with particular person that can be achieved by multiple verification.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Alex. I had also tried by formatting my device and again after logging in New Device alert is coming. Also, one of my friend is travelling, he also get this alert on same device at different locations. So, what we can predict is that some of the google background service do some metadata entry in our device when we logged in, and it works in conjunction of that entry plus IP range or geo location.